# Are the texts of Magha Purana, Kartika Purana and Vaisakha Purana available in Sanskrit or English?

Tags: puranas, vayupurana

Are the texts of Magha Purana, Kartika Purana and Vaisakha Purana available in English or Sanskrit. If they are taken from major puranas, which puranas contain them? Magha purana is said to be part of Vayu purana. But I cannot find it in [here](https://archive.org/details/VayuPuranaG.V.TagarePart1) or [here](https://archive.org/details/VayuPuranaG.V.TagarePart2).